# how to inline this jquery.attr if block

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
if (toDo.Href) {
    $('#submit').attr("href", toDo.Href);
} else {
    $('#submit').removeAttr("href");
}
```

It feels to me like there must be some way to do this in one line. For a class there is toggleclass but no such for attr.

---

### clarification

My code got substantially clearer when I used .toggle and .toggleClass to inline other ifs in my code. I was hoping there was something similar for attr.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
toDo.Href ? $('#submit').attr("href", toDo.Href) : $('#submit').removeAttr("href");
```

This basically says:

```
(condition) ? if true : if false
```

Comment: well yes. if and ternary are semantic sugar for each other. I was hoping to combine the $('#submit') so that it is clear that I am only modifying the attr of the tag.